# Loading multiple csv into BQ table on event trigger

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, bq

i am trying to load multiple csv files into table by below code but it is failing:
Can anyone let me know where i am wrong:
##################

```
def csv_loader(data, context):
        client = bigquery.Client()
        dataset_id = os.environ['DATASET']
        dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
        job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
        field_delimiter="|",
        write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
        skip_leading_rows=1,
         )

        # get the URI for uploaded CSV in GCS from 'data'
        uri = 'gs://' + os.environ['BUCKET'] + '/' + data['name']
        # lets do this
        load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
                uri,
                dataset_ref.table(os.environ['TABLE'])

        load_job.result()  # wait for table load to complete.
        print('Job finished.')
        destination_table = client.get_table(dataset_ref.table(os.environ['TABLE']))
        print('Loaded {} rows.'.format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

###################

Above works fine if schema is mentioned for one file but with multiple files gives error.Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: Do all files have the same schema? Please also include the error message in your post.

Comment: No schema is different,i am doing schema auto detect .Not getting any error and data is not getting loaded.

Comment: I don't see the schema autodetect flag in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your last comment, schemas are different and you want to use schema auto detect. However, I don't see the flag in your code and neither see you passing the job_config variable in the job load method.

Try something as below:

Note: I added the flag `autodetect=True`, in the `job_config` variable and also passed the `job_config` variable in the **load_table_from_uri()** function.

```
def csv_loader(data, context):
        client = bigquery.Client()
        dataset_id = os.environ['DATASET']
        dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
        job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        autodetect=True,
        source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
        field_delimiter="|",
        write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
        skip_leading_rows=1,
         )

        # get the URI for uploaded CSV in GCS from 'data'
        uri = 'gs://' + os.environ['BUCKET'] + '/' + data['name']
        # lets do this
        load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
                uri,
                dataset_ref.table(os.environ['TABLE'],
                job_config=job_config
               )

        load_job.result()  # wait for table load to complete.
        print('Job finished.')
        destination_table = client.get_table(dataset_ref.table(os.environ['TABLE']))
        print('Loaded {} rows.'.format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

Comment: ok got it now i have question so in env.yaml do I need to pass tables or it will autodetect based on event name

Comment: Did it work? From the documentation, table name should be in this format: # table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name". If you're using environment variable to get the name of the table you have to feed the env variable somewhere (either in your env.yaml or where/how you're deploying your code).

Comment: No error and data is not getting loaded also

Comment: How are you deploying this code? Cloud Function? have you checked Cloud Logging to see whether there are any errors there or not?

Comment: deploying through console..yes i am looking into Cloud function logging

Comment: There has to be some sort of info/error in Cloud Logging. Go to Cloud Logging explorer and do not filter anything and run the Cloud Function again. Most likely the error is coming from BigQuery job and not the Cloud Function code.

Comment: you are right ,I got bad characters which I  replaced in file and after that it worked fine. thank you for your help and support